# Session cookies getting 'lost' when payment portal process completes

Tags: php, stripe-payments, cgi

I have recently taken over the running of a hotel website which is linked to a bespoke booking management system.  Because of this, it was simpler to leave all the previous developer's PHP code in place on the booking and payment pages of the website (The site uses stripe.com to process payments)

When a payment is processed, a PHP script is used to create a number of session cookies to record things like Room Number, Booking REF Cost etc then the site enters the Stripe portal which picks up the cookies and processes the payment - this is where things seem to go wrong.

The payment is processed successfully, all the info is displayed on the Stripe screen so I know it's reaching their server  however when the browser is the forwarded back to the payment successful page on my new site, all the information stored by the cookies seems to vanish so the confirmation page fields are all blank.

Just to reiterate, this is code which was used on the old site for several years and which is still working on that site now (it's still live) - the info only disappears when Stripe returns to my new site.

So far as I can see, the PHP is identical on old and new sites.  The only major differences are the domain hosting the old and new site are different (the new site is on our testing server) and obviously the servers are different.

The version of PHP used by the old site is 5.6 which I know is deprecated however I'm paying our hosting company (IONOS) £7.99 per month to enable support for this version and everything to this point has worked fine.

I've talked to Stripe support (useless) in case it was a security issue linked to the new testing server domain needing to be registered with them - they say it isn't.  I'm hoping I don't get a succession of 'upgrade to the latest version of PHP' comments on here - we will do that eventually but it's so close to being done - this is one of the final tasks.

Comment: Dont Stripe return you all the inputs along with their result information

Comment: _the domain hosting the old and new site are different_ That's the reason.  Cookies aren't shared across domains.

Comment: But it works perfectly well on the old site?  The new site creates its own cookies then goes to Stripe then comes back?